# Event to update a control in the right moment

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls

I have a User Control displaying some data and a button that displays a popup that allows the user to add data. Then the users enters the data and clicks OK and the pop-up closes. The problem is that the form still displays the old data. To what event should I wire `DataReload()` to see the change immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the FormClosed event of your popup:

```
popUp.FormClosed += (o, e) => DataReload();
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the "popup"? A dialog?

If it is shown modally with ShowDialog(), then it will not return until the user hits OK and it returns its result, so you can just call DataReload() right afterwards, as in:

```
MyDialog dlg = new MyDialog();
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    DataReload();
}
```

Comment: It's a regular form, sorry. It's closed by this.Close() at the end of the data-adding code.